# Were there any cases of woodpeckers damaging Shuttle External Tank insulation other than that of STS-70?

Tags: space-shuttle, history, external-tank, insulation

While researching information about Shuttle External Tank insulation, I came across this quite unusual problem: woodpeckers!

The Wikipedia entry on [STS-70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-70) states that:

> ... on 31 May 1995 shuttle managers assessed damage to the External Tank of STS-70 caused by nesting flicker woodpeckers. The damage consisted of about 71 holes (ranging in size from 4 inches in diameter to 1/2 inch in diameter) in the ETs thermal protection foam insulation.

[This source](https://curiosity.com/topics/that-time-some-woodpeckers-shut-down-a-nasa-space-shuttle-launch-curiosity/) claims that Bruce Buckingham, a spokesman at the Kennedy Space Center, mentioned to New York Times the following:

> There's been some history to this kind of problem, but not to this degree.

Same source states that, as a result of the incident, NASA set up the Bird Investigation Review and Deterrent (BIRD) team, known as "pecker patrol".
There is interesting video about it:

It seems the crew of STS-70 even had a bit of fun about the accident:
 [image]
There are some more images here (including damage to insulation and artificial owls set up by the pecker patrol team): http://ohioastronaut.com/sts-70

Given the spokesman statement (about some history to this problem), were there any other cases of woodpeckers spotted on ET and/or damaging insulation, either before or after STS-70?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STS-70 is the only case of woodpecker damage I know of.

If you search the *[Space Shuttle Missions Summary](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110001406/downloads/20110001406.pdf)* document for "woodpecker", that is the only hit.

[image]

[Image Source](https://www.npr.org/sections/krulwich/2011/03/07/134329438/eleven-inch-earthlings-attack-space-shuttle)

Incidentally, they were Northern Flickers, nice birds.

[image]

[Image Source](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Northern_Flicker/id)